# Using skipLocationChange in NativeScript/Angular app causes the 'skipped location' to appear briefly on the screen

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nativescript

I am routing to a new details component named 'comdataApproval' with the onItemTap() event. After the user does some stuff, will navigate them back to the 'master component'. I do not want the user to be able to navigate back to this detail component after they have been redirected from it. I use `skipLocationChange: true` to try to achieve this.

When they click the back button on the main component it does what you would expect and navigates them to the component they were at before accessing the 'master component'. **However,** in the process the 'comdataApproval' component shows on the screen for a brief amount of time (less than a second) and then the user is navigated to the correct component.

```
 constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private comdataService: ComdataService) {
    // Use the component constructor to inject providers.        
}

  onItemTap(args){                    
    let navigationExtras : NavigationExtras ={
        queryParams: {
            index: args.index,
            comdataRecords: JSON.stringify(this.comdataRecords)
        },
        skipLocationChange: true
    };

    this.router.navigate(["/comdataApproval"], navigationExtras);        
}
```

Navigation back to Master Component.

```
 .then(() => {
         //do routing here
         this.router.navigate(["/comdata"]);
    });
```

I am not sure why this component is being shown. It is like the app is navigating to the detail component then navigating back to the correct component in history. Is there any way to prevent this brief 'pause' that occurs?

**Edit:**
Example Navigation:

**homePage -> comdataPage -> comdataApproval -> comdataPage**

From here back button could be pressed. If pressed it should go to the homePage, not the comdataApproval page. But, when it is pressed it goes to the comdataApproval page and then to the homePage rather than directly to the homePage.

Comment: You want to prevent user from navigating back to master page, am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that worked for me in my situation hopefully it helps someone else.

The navigation: 
**homePage -> comdataPage -> comdataApproval -> comdataPage**

My problem was from **comdataApproval** to **comdataPage** I needed to reload the contents from an API. This is why I was routing directly and using skipLocation in the previous route. To avoid the pause issue and reload the contents I used the following code:

comdataApproval:

```
this.router.backToPreviousPage();
```

comdataPage:

```
 this.page.on('navigatingTo', (data) => {
        if(data.isBackNavigation)
            this.ngOnInit();    
      }     
    )
```

And then in ngOnInit I call my API. I still have no idea why the pausing issue was occurring on when using skipLocation.

Additionally I couldn't use clearHistory, which was suggested in another answer, because then when a user pressed back the app would close rather than the expected navigation to a previous page.

Comment: I think I am having pretty much exactly the same problem. could you show where you placed the `this.router.backToPreviousPage();` - in ngOnInit?
And where did you place the second codesnippet?

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to hide the default `NavigationButton` and place your own `ActionItem` that looks like a back button. On Android, you will also have to listen to the [activityBackPressed](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#android-activity-events) event and cancel the back navigation.

Then navigate to `comdata` with `clearHistory` flag set to `true` when user clicks on your `ActionItem` (custom back button). For Android, you will have to do the same in `activityBackPressed` event too in order to keep the behaviour intact across platforms.

```
this.router.navigate(["/comdata"], { clearHistory: true });
```